# What's wrong with my solution for the following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following DE:

$$y'+2xy-xy^4=0$$

It's a Bernoulli equation, so I converted it to:
$v'-6xv=-3x$ 
and the integrating factor being $e^{-3x^2}$ 
after doing the necessary steps, I find myself with :
$ve^{-3x^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}  e^{-3x^2}+c$

However, the solution I get is $\dfrac{1}{y^3}=\dfrac{1}{2}+ce^{-3x^2}$ which seems to be wrong somehow. 
Any idea what went wrong? 
I hope the details I submitted are enough.

Comment: Use latex please http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

The solution you obtain for $v$ is correct. Moreover, it's given by:

$$v(x) = 1/2 + c \, e^{3x^2}, \quad c \in \mathbb{R}.$$

The change of variables $v = 1/y^3$ leads to the final solution:

$$ 1/y^3 = 1/2 + c \, e^{3x^2},$$

which is an implicit form of expressing your result. It appears to be a typo on the book your are consulting/studying from, so good work!

Of course, note that $y = 0$ is also a solution, so the solution presented above is far from unique!

Cheers!

Comment: well, now I notice that the solution you worked out is a bit different - with $e^{3x^2}$ rather than $e^{-3x^2}$

Comment: Of course! Note that, when you solve for $v$ after finding the integrating factor, the $e^{-3x^2}$ factor in the LHS becomes a $e^{3x^2}$ when passing to the RHS.

Comment: I don't get it. I didn't move it from side to side - I multiplied both sides by the factor. Why should the sign change?

Answer (score 0):

make a change of variable $v = y^{-3}$ or $v^{-1/3} = y$ in $y'+2xy-xy^4=0$ we get
$$-\dfrac{1}{3} v^{-4/3}v^\prime + 2x v^{-1/3} = xv^{-4/3} $$ which can be rewritten as 
$$\dfrac{dv}{dx} - 6xv = -3x \text{ or } \dfrac{d(ve^{-3x^2})}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-3x^2}\right)$$

this give $ v = \dfrac{1}{2} + Ce^{3x^2}$ for any constant $C$. going back to the variable $y$ gives $$ \frac{1}{y^3} = \dfrac{1}{2} + Ce^{3x^2}$$

Comment: But this is exactly what I got to, and it seems to be wrong - at least according to Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Are you sure that what WA gives you is not the same? I get, after some manipulation: $y^3 = 2/(1+e^{3x^2+6C})$. What happens then if you identify $c$ as $e^{6C}$?

Comment: I guess you are right - it's all a question of algebraic manipulation. Thanks.